# Atho 10 WiFi not working properly

Tags: wireless, 15.10, atheros

This January I bought a new MSI Stealth laptop and immediately installed Ubuntu on it only to realize that my Wifi card was at the time unsupported.
I have the Atheros KillerWirless 1525 chip. I occasionaly would check every couple of weeks to see if it would work yet. Finally I found a way to install Ath10 and after many different setup attempts I got the Wifi to work as it normally should. Sadly I just upgraded to Ubuntu Wiley 15.10 and my Wifi runs incredibly slow. It still connects but takes several minutes to get to a Webpage. Sometimes I will even get the system error message and it says ath10 stopped working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What did you do to get it working?

Comment: I used steps from this website  http://blog.hyperexpert.com/how-to-get-killer-wireless-ac-1525-working-with-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Wily probably doesn't need that fix, so remove it.  If you haven't deleted the file, double click on it and choose remove to uninstall the dkms file in Ubuntu Software Center.
Or `sudo dpkg -r ath10k-dkms` in terminal

Then in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware
sudo cp -r ath10k /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been using this fix for about ten minutes and everything seems to be operating smoothly. Your a life saver.