# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi connection issues ("connected" with packet loss)

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am using a Lenovo E51. First issue is that my Wifi is connected however it constantly has zero bars when looking at connection strength.

The other issue being more serious. Occasionally (roughly every hour) when using the wifi my web pages stop loading and all traffic through the internet becomes null and void. I have pinged my wifi access point during one of these connection drops, and it shows roughly 17 000 ms with 15% packet-loss. However, if I ping the access point from another laptop I do not have the same issue.

When i disable my wifi and use ethernet connection my ping and packet-loss return to normal.

#### More Details

```
sudo lshw -class network

   description: Wireless interface
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 30
   serial: c8:ff:28:6f:d5:3b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-28-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=10.0.42.172 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:128 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

```
dmesg | grep ath10k

[   54.031166] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   54.267795] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   56.149768] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   56.149769] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   56.158505] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[35286.808388] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[35294.004448] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[37307.506326] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer 30:91:8f:91:88:8b: -110
[37307.562587] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[38438.809538] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer 30:91:8f:91:88:8b: -110
[43803.521938] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43895.527856] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43912.384595] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43912.418986] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43912.470225] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43912.490166] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43917.679053] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43943.076183] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43943.076530] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[43943.076949] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

Let me know if there is any other information you guys need. Thanks in advance for any/all help.

EDIT: Firmware update was unsuccessful - dmesg | grep ath10k returns same error

```
dmesg | grep ath10k

[   54.031166] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   54.267795] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   56.149768] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   56.149769] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   56.158505] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Update: I have also tried updating my kernel version from version 4.4.0-31-generic to 4.4.9-040409-generic with no success.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

I have also tried as suggested in [Atho 10 WiFi not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693114/atho-10-wifi-not-working-properly) namely:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware
sudo cp -r -i * /lib/firmware/ath10k/
```

dmesg | grep ath10k errors still persist along with connection issues.

Comment: Wireless Chipset
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
I have tried kernel and firmware updates and they did not resolve the issue

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the problem from 15.10, i.e. just "upgrading the firmware" isn't going to help for people already running the latest firmware. For my qca9377 ath10k_pci device the problem with the disconnects and drops was fixed in some vanilla kernel between 4.4 and 4.8.12. See my comment below : http://askubuntu.com/questions/806097/ubuntu-16-04-wifi-connection-issues-connected-with-packet-loss/806104?noredirect=1#comment1319350_806104 . I'm running 4.8.12 now and it's working great.

Comment: @sabujp I have updated my kernel to 4.8.0 and am still getting the error. Will check other kernel versions and let you know. So you are not getting the error from dmesg | grep ath10k since you updated to 4.8.12?

Comment: I'm using 4.8.12 and have model qca9377 . The only time I still have problems is sometimes after coming out of suspend it takes several minutes for it to try to connect by itself, so I restart the wifi stack with this so that it connects immediately : sudo rmmod -f ath10k_pci ath10k_core ath mac80211 cfg80211
&& sudo modprobe ath10k_pci ath10k_core ath mac80211 cfg80211
&& sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart ;
nohup nm-applet & . Put that in a script in your path.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try later firmware for your device. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.159_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and let us know if the performance has improved.

Note to searchers: The version number, 1.159 in this case, changes from time to time. This version number may be invalid at some point in the future.

Comment: i have done as you suggested but it seems that after my reboot that my wireless interface doesn't display when I use the ifconfig -a command. Please note that i am new to Linux and would appreciate your patience.

Comment: Now that you've updated the firmware, what does this tell us? `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: Nothing. It only prompts for the next command.

Comment: EDIT: after a second reboot the network interface exists and network strength shows, however "Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2" error still persists

Comment: Now can you stay connected? Is there any improvement in pings?

Comment: I no longer have ping issue but my wifi disconnects occasionally.  When i ping my access point it says host is unreachable. My route table is empty. When i disable wifi and enable wifi it doesn't connect. I have read that it might be a kernel issue. I am running kernel 4.4.0-31-generic. Will update kernel and post the results.

Comment: I have updated my original post

Comment: For me it seems this problem with the "no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!" errors  have been fixed in some kernel between 4.4 and 4.8.12. I'm currently running 4.8.12 installed by https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities . I was also running the latest firmware for a long time (it's still pretty old : https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA9377/hw1.0), but that alone didn't help.

Comment: @sabujp I suggest that you start your own new question. We'll be happy to help.

Comment: I don't have a new question, if you do a search for ath10k_pci no channel configured; ignoring frame(s), this is like the first hit, which also describes the same problems with loss of connection with 1/3 or less signal. No one's solution worked and I didn't have time to mail LKML. I just waited  a few weeks and luckily an upgraded kernel fixed it, just offering a suggestion if others are having this problem.